# setting up a react project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am setting up a react project from scratch using webpack and babel. While running it is throwing an error. Please help me.

I am attaching the screen shots of error. My babel is not getting installed properly. Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: try https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: Can you screenshot your package.json also. Perhaps you don't have babel installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install babel-core babel-loader --save-dev
```

You have to install the packages as dev-dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### `webpack.config.js`

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
```

### `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-2"]
}
```

### `package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.3",
    "webpack": "^4.15.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
    ....
```